# Stuck in a for loop entering values to an array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, scanf

I am trying to practice with C by making a bubble sort program. The problem until now seems to be that the for loop that is giving values to the cells of the array is stuck after the condition is no longer fulfilled but it doesn't seem to be executing the commands in the loop. I don't know what is happening exactly and I have added some extra lines to see what is happening an these were my conclusions. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int *sort(int *array)
{
    int finish = 1;
    while (finish = 1)
    {
        finish = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(array); i++)
        {
            if ((array + i) > (array + i + 1))
            {
                swap(array + i, array + i + 1);
                finish = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
int main()
{
    int s, res;
    printf("Give me the size of the array being sorted(larger than 1) : ");
    do
    {
        res = scanf("%d", &s);
        if (res != 1)
        {
            printf("Wrong Input!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (s < 2)
            printf("Only numbers equal or larger than 2\n");

    } while (s < 2);
    int array[s];
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i += 1)
    {
        scanf("%d", array + i);
        printf("%d %d %d\n\n", *(array + i), i, i < s); // I used this to check if my values were ok
    }
    printf("end of reading the array"); //I added this line to see if I would exit the for loop. I am not seeing this message
    sort(array);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
        printf("%d\n\n", array + i);
    printf("Array has been sorted! Have a nice day!\n\n************************************************************");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(array)` won't do what you think it does. Look up "array to pointer decay".

Comment: In the `printf` call after the reading loop, try adding a trailing newline. Also please [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line. The problem is not where you think it is, the output of that `printf` call is just not written to the terminal.

Comment: Also `while (finish = 1)`-->`while (finish == 1)`

Comment: Also, `(array + i) > (array + i + 1)` will not do what you expect either. That condition will *always* be false. Don't use pointer arithmetic for "arrays", always use array indexing.

Comment: @Swordfish I thought `int array[s];` should be an array....right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, but in the `sort` function `array` is not an array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah...TL;DR..i was looking in `main()`.. :)

Comment: Please always enable warnings in your compiler. The line `while (finish = 1)` should cause some warning about an assignment in a condition.

Comment: wow guys.. I'm really sorry for this super stupid question. Thank you for pointing out the finish = 1 I'm sorry for wasting your time. The program executed fully without the expected results but I'll work on that there are definitely other mistakes I can sort out. I'll work on this. I'll also stick to using array indexing for this program. Thank you so much and I'm sincerely sorry for wasting your time. I learned a lot thank you guys!

Comment: `sizeof(array)` is misused both times.  In the `sort()` function, `sizeof(array)` returns the number of bytes that make up the **pointer** `int *array`.  In `main`, `sizeof(array)` returns the number of **bytes** in the array `int array[s];` and not the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the annotations in the code:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t  1)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

int *sort(int *array, size_t size)  // needs an extra parameter to know the size of the array
{
    int finish = 1;
    while (finish /* = 1 * you don't want assignment, you want comparison: */ == 1)
    {
        finish = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i /* <= sizeof(array) */ < size - 1; i++)  // i should be of type size_t
        {
            // if ((array + i) > (array + i + 1)) you are not dereferencing:
            if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) 
            {
                // swap(array + i, array + i + 1);  // easier to read imho:
                swap(&array[i], &array[i + 1]);
                finish = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;  // why does this function return anything? it is never used.
}
int main()
{
    int s; /* , res;  no need for an extra variable res */
    printf("Give me the size of the array being sorted(larger than 1) : ");
    do
    {
        // res = scanf("%d", &s);
        // if (res != 1)
        if (scanf("%d", &s) != 1)
        {
            printf("Wrong Input!\n");
            // exit(1);  // should be EXIT_FAILURE. Use return instead of exit() when in main().
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (s < 2)
            printf("Only numbers equal or larger than 2\n");

    } while (s < 2);
    int array[s];
    for (int i = 0; i < s; /* i += 1* idiomatic: */ ++i)  // size_t would be the correct type for s and i.
    {
        scanf("%d", /* array + i  use indexes: */ &array[i]);
        printf("%d %d %d\n\n", array[i], i, i < s);  // again: indexes. i < s is allready ensured by the condition of the for-loop
    }
    printf("end of reading the array");
    // sort(array);  // sort will have no idea about the size of array use
    sort(array, s); // instead.

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < /* sizeof(array) 2) */ s; i++)
        printf("%d\n\n", /* array + i * again you don't dereference */ array[i]);
    printf("Array has been sorted! Have a nice day!\n\n************************************************************");
    return 0;
}
```

1) `size_t` is the type that is guaranteed to be big enough to hold all sizes of objects in memory and indexes into them. The conversion specifier for `scanf()` is `"%zu"`.

2) `sizeof(array)` in `main()` will yield the number of bytes in `array`, but you want the number of elements so you'd have to use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`. But thats not needed since you already know its size. It is `s`.

Comment: You cannot imagine how helpful this is thank you so much!! I learned a lot from this and you expanded my understanding of C thank you!

Comment: "You cannot imagine how helpful" Yes, i can. i learned C++ the very hard way without internet access and q+a sites or forums using Borland C++ 3.1 on DOS 6.22^^

Comment: `i +1 < size` handles the corner  case of `size == 0`. It is better than `i < size - 1` which will iterate for a long time as it is effectively `i < SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
printf("end of reading the array");
```

has no line feed at the end of the string. This is a problem because `printf` is part of the family of functions called "buffered IO". The C library maintains a buffer of the things you want to print and only sends them to the terminal if the buffer gets full or it encounters `\n` in the stream of characters. You will not see, `end of reading the array` on your screen until after you have printed a line feed. You only do this *after* calling `sort()`. So all you know is your program is getting into an infinite loop at some point before the end of `sort`.

So there are actually three loops that could be infinite: the `for` loop you identified, the `while` loop in `sort` and the `for` loop inside the `while` loop. As the other answers point out, you have made the classic mistake of using assignment in the `while` conditional

```
while (finish = 1)
//            ^ not enough equals signs
```

Unless your C compiler is really old, it is probably outputting a warning on that line. You should heed warnings.

Also, you should learn to use a debugger sooner rather than later. Believe me, it will save you a lot of time finding bugs.

Answer (score -1):

In the sort function `sizeof(array)` returns the size of the pointer. (you can check it by yourself using `printf("%d", sizeof(array)`.

The solution is to change your function to:

```
int sort(int* array, size_t size) { ... }
```

and call it with the correct array size:

```
sort(array, s);
```

Comment: "returns the same as sizeof(int)" nope.

Comment: "`printf("%s", sizeof(array))`" nope, nope.

Comment: Does the sizeof not return the size of the pointer type? That was always my understanding of it.

Comment: Ok, I should have tested it myself before answering, it returns the size of the pointer type.

Comment: Should be using `%zu` not `%d` for printing out the `sizeof` something